# Sideload Updated Windows 7 app to Windows 8 Phone XAP

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, sideloading

I have upgraded the Windows Phone 7 Barcode Scanning app to a Windows 8 Phone app and I deployed the app to my Windows 8 Phone. The package is .xap. How do I sideload this app to another phone? I am using this app for business purposes and it will not be available on the Windows Store.

Zune never connects to my Win8 phone and I am unable to use the Win7 Phone Application Deployment tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like you used the Windows Phone 7 deployment tool for WP7, just use the Windows Phone 8 deployment tool for WP8. It's located in the folder:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v8.0\Tools\XAP Deployment

Of course, that is if you have a developer-unlocked device.

Answer (score 0):

Can we restrict our applications to run on particular devices by using the device id? means the application should run on only registered devices